# Apex callout with Oauth Token from Trigger

Tags: apex, oauth2, httprequest

I am currently trying to make a webservice callout via Apex to update some fields on an object.
We have an insert trigger that is linked to an Apex handler class.  To use the webservice, I must first use a POST method to get an access token, then a GET request to get the information I need.

The problem I'm running into is I have to use a @future method to get the Access Token since it is being called from a trigger which causes 2 problems: 1. I cant return the token to a public variable in the class and 2. the context is now asynchronous so I cant guarantee the order of exception for the GET request to follow the POST request.

I was thinkin about using Queueable apex to be called after the POST request.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have to use a @future method to get the Access Token since it is being called from a trigger

Minor correction: you have to use Asynchronous Apex. You don't have to use an `@future` method; you just must leave the trigger context.

> 1. I cant return the token to a public variable in the class

Correct, but it wouldn't matter anyway because you can't *use* that token in the trigger context - you can't make any callouts there, whether GET or POST.

> 2. the context is now asynchronous so I cant guarantee the order of exception for the GET request to follow the POST request.

This is not quite right. Your asynchronous context is allowed to make *multiple* callouts, so long as you stay within governor limits. It's fine for your asynchronous Apex to make a POST followed by a GET; you simply must do all work that you wish to do with the results of those calls inside the async context or in a new job that you chain into. You can't return that data to a synchronous trigger context.

All other things being equal, I would recommend you use a Queueable Apex job because that interface allows a lot more flexibility than future methods.